# I am looking for a word that means "to use whatever is available as a resource"

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

The word would mean "to use whatever is available as a resource".

For example,

> If I do not have a ruler, I will just ______ to anything that is straight.

What is this word?

Comment: The usual expression is the transitive multi-word verb 'make do with'.

Comment: In your example, you could just use *use* and be easily understood.  "**If** I do not have a rule, I will just use anything that is straight." The *if* makes it plain that the rule was your preferred option.

Comment: You have a number of options (*appropriate*, *exploit*, *co-opt*); it's interesting that many seem to have negative connotations. I think *'making do'* is a good choice here.

Comment: The adjective "ad hoc" might apply.  Or any of its synonyms:     extemporaneous, ad-lib, down and dirty, extemporary, extempore, impromptu, improvisational, improvised, offhand, offhanded, off-the-cuff, snap, spur-of-the-moment, unconsidered, unplanned, unpremeditated, unprepared, unrehearsed, unstudied.  "Improvise" is perhaps the term you are looking for.

Comment: The OP is asking for a specific verb to fill in a specific blank. There are like two verbs tops that do the job, and both of them do the job most superbly, and both of them have been mentioned by now. Yet hordes of people keep falling over themselves trying to come up with the most weirdestest alternatives. I am forced to start pruning the comments.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps the word you seek is *[resort](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/resort)*:-

> to have recourse for use, help, or accomplishing something, often as a final option. [Webster's College Dictionary]
>
> (usually foll by to) to have recourse (to) for help, use, etc [Collins English Dictionary]

So your sentence would read:-

> If I do not have a ruler, I will just resort to anything that is
>   straight.

Comment: +1: see also [as a last resort](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/as+a+last+resort)

Comment: But the question states 'what is available' which doesn't necessarily infer there is only *one* thing remaining ...

Answer (score 3):

Came back to this after a year or so. There is a word that strictly answers your question:

> If I do not have a ruler, I will just **default** to anything that is straight.

I think that also addresses Lamar Latrell's comments on both my and Brian Hooper's answers.

My original answer required slightly rephrasing your sentence:

> If I do not have a ruler, I will just **settle** for anything that is straight.

Comment: This works in the  context of the (reworded) sentence, but doesn't work as a answer to "a word that means 'to use whatever is available as a resource'” - yes/no?

Answer (score 2):

*Make do*, already offered, hints that the alternative will be less than ideal. That may be the case if a straight edge doesn't meet all of the requirements, but a straight edge will be somewhat sufficient.

> to make, provide, or arrange from whatever materials are readily available ([Dictionary.com #3](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/improvise?s=t))

If I do not have a ruler, I will just **improvise** *with* anything that is straight.

Answer (score 1):

***[Substitute](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/substitute)***:

> A person or *thing* acting or serving in place of another.

But specifically the verb, and in your context:

> "If I do not have a rule, I will **substitute** in anything that is straight."

Answer (score 1):

I will just use [*Turn to*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/evidence) whose usage is very clear in the following example in Oxford Dictionary:

> Go on **to consider** next:

We can now turn to another aspect of the problem.

Comment: This works in the context of the given sentence, but doesn't work as a answer to "a word that means “to use whatever is available as a resource” - you think ?

Answer (score 0):

To stick to the example sentence as it is, the word ***stick*** may work.

> If I do not have a ruler, I will just ***stick*** to anything that is
>   straight.

ODO:

> **[stick](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/stick) to**  [Phrasal Verb]
>   **1** Continue or **confine oneself to** doing or **using (a particular thing)**
>     ‘I'll stick to bitter lemon, thanks’

Answer (score 0):

The use of routine or common substitutions are covered well by the other answers.  In a case involving thinking way outside the box, people sometimes use a reference to the TV character **MacGuyver**, as in "do a MacGuyver" or "MacGuyver myself out of a situation".

The theme of the show was a ridiculously resourceful guy who figured out how to get out of impossible situations using common items on hand in unusual ways.  See http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=MacGuyver